# menu expandable CSS script on hover or Onclick on a link / button

Tags: javascript, css, menu, css-transitions

I want to create a css with following specifications :

1. When I click on a link / button in a form, it should expand its options horizontally.
2. It should collapse after selecting the option.

**EDIT:**

To elaborate my query, let me attach the few images which will explain the exact query.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Step 1. Onhover or OnClick on Image Field, it should expand a Div included with 4 Images.
Step 2. If I select one of the Four Image, the collapse the Div and Display the Selected image in the Image field.

Please suggest the best possible code.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

well..hopefully i have understood you correctly..

```js
var expandFn = function(){
 var wrappBl = document.getElementsByClassName('expand')[0];
 var trigg = document.getElementById('trigger');
 var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var elArr = [].slice.call(el);
 this.getAction = function(){
   trigg.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(wrappBl.classList.contains('active')){
     wrappBl.classList.remove('active');
    }
    
    else {
     wrappBl.classList.add('active');
    }
   });
 
 }
 getAction()

 this.checkIf = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < elArr.length; i++) {
   elArr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( this.checked === true){
    wrappBl.classList.remove('active');
    };
   })
   
  }
 }
 checkIf();
}
setTimeout(function(){expandFn();},0)
```

```css
.expand input,
.expand label{
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
}
div.expand{
 width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 400ms ease, opacity 400ms ease;
    transition: transform 400ms ease, opacity 400ms ease;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.expand.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <a id="trigger" href="#">expand</a>

 <div class="expand">
  <h4>title of the option</h4>
  <input name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="option1">choose that</label>
  <input name="option2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="option2">choose that</label>
  <input name="option3" type="checkbox">
  <label for="option3">choose that</label>
 </div>
</div>
```